# Salesforce CPQ document preview rendering incorrectly

Tags: pdf, cpq, richtextarea, preview

When I enter the following into a Rich Text Area field:

[image]

this is what renders in the document preview:

[image]

and this is the HTML from the Rich Text Area field:

```
<p>Normal text 
 <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">color text</span> normal text
</p>
<p>Normal text 
 <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
  <strong>bold color text </strong>
 </span>normal text
</p>
<p>Normal text 
 <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
  <strong><u>bold underlined color text</u></strong></span> normal text
</p>
```

There are no extra line breaks, the content looks just fine on the record page and yet it breaks in the document preview. Any idea how this could be potentially fixed?